# glFrustrum new dimensions?

Tags: android, opengl-es

OpenGLES 1.0 is confusing me. I understand that normally in OpenGL the grid is -1,-1,-1 to 1, 1, 1. I am using OpenGL for 2D only, but I am wondering how I can get the new dimensions of the grid after applying frustum and other projections?

Answer (score 0):

Check this site http://www.songho.ca/opengl/ You should understand all the math of opengl in order to debug  errors in the future. For the projection matrix, this is the specific url: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html